# Force X axis to only have whole number ticks, MaxNLocator and MultipleLocator do not work

Tags: matplotlib

I can't seem to force my subplot in matplotlib to have only integer values. I first divided my x-axis values by a variable fps (frames per second) using this:

```
ax1 = speciesGraph.add_subplot(111)
...
ticks_x = ticker.FuncFormatter(lambda x, pos: '{0:g}'.format(x/fps))
ax1.xaxis.set_major_formatter(ticks_x)
```

And the values on the x-axis get divided by fps, although the ticks are at numbers like 0.69, 0.77, 0.85, etc. I want to change the ticks to whole numbers only after the division, but when I write

```
ax1.xaxis.set_major_locator(ticker.MaxNLocator(integer=True))
```

afterwards, the x axis isn't getting changed to integer values. 
Does anyone know what could be the issue?

Comment: A whole number divided by `fps` is in general not a whole number anymore.

Comment: yeah I wanted to convert from frames per second to seconds, so I need to divide by fps. This changes my x value increments to decimals, and I want to change them back to whole numbers

Comment: Why don't you plot x/fps in the first place?

Comment: Because I'm passing in a single array with its indices as the x-axis and its values as the y-axis. I'd have to make two arrays with the x-axis divided by fps, and the y-axis otherwise. I have a dictionary with "species" as a key and an array as a value, and each species is getting plotted onto a single graph.

Comment: Yes, you can pass the index divided by fps as x coordinates instead.

Comment: Okay, thanks! Is there a better way to do this other than making a new list from [0, 1, 2, 3...n], and then dividing it by the fps for each species? It's just that some of the species' array lengths are different, so I wouldn't be able to just make one list of x-coordinates for all of them

Comment: Suppose that previously you did `plt.plot(y)`. What I'm proposing is to do `plt.plot(np.arange(len(y))/fps, y)` instead.

Comment: Oh, it was actually a list and not an array, but I may change this. thanks!